# функция ajax выводит undifined при return'е значений data

Tags: jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте!

Пробую создать такую функцию:

```
function ajax_query(type, query)
{
    // отправка запроса
    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: '<?=url_query?>',
        data:
        {
            my_query: query
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            var result = data;
            if(result == '')
            {
                return '1';
            }
            else
            {
                return '';
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Пробую проверять, что пришло ajax'ом:

```
console.log(ajax_query('POST', 'query value'))
```

В любом случаи выводится `undefined`, есть или нет результатов с ajax'a. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызов `$.ajax` является асинхронным. Т.е. результат возвращается сразу после отправки запроса и независимо от получения ответа.

При этом `return result;`, результат которого вы ожидали получить вообще возвращает результат другой (вложенной) функции, т.е. формально к `ajax_query` никакого отношения не имеет.

Корректнее выполнять какую-то логику после выполнения запроса:

```
function ajax_query(type, query)
{
    // отправка запроса
    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: '<?=url_query?>',
        data:
        {
            my_query: query
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            var result = data;
            // какая-то логика обработки, например:
            console.log(result );
        }
    });
}
```

**UPD** альтернативным вариантом будет отключение асинхронного вызова, но это является плохой практикой. Не тестировал, но должно работать

```
function ajax_query(type, query)
{
    var result;
    // отправка запроса
    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: '<?=url_query?>',
        async: false,
        data:
        {
            my_query: query
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            if(data == '')
            {
                result = '1';
            }
            else
            {
                result = '';
            }
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Там все норм. Если писать так как вы написали. Суть моей проблемы в том, чтоб узнать, пришел ли ответ от сервера, и какой он пустой или нет. Если не пустой, то через функцию с ним уже работать.

Comment: например чтоб можно было использовать примерно в таких вот целях: `if(ajax_query('POST', 'query value') == '') ...`

Comment: Как я уже сказал, корректнее как раз внутри функции-обработчика `success` и делать проверку результата и выполнять оставшуюся логику. Т.е. вместо написания последовательного работать с асинхронным. Например вместо `шаг1; if(ajax_query(type, query)) шаг2;` сделать (в самом примитивном варианте) `шаг1; ajax_query(type, query, function() {шаг2;}); ` только переопределить тогда саму функцию: `function ajax_query(type, query, successHandler) ... success: function(data) {if data !='' successHandler()}...`

Comment: Попробую, спасибо